# In Xcode my Mac app launches curl, but -o can't write to disk

Tags: swift, macos, curl, xcode11.4

In terminal this works:

```
/usr/bin/curl --connect-timeout 10 --max-time 60 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles -o /Users/username/Desktop/wikiData

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  909k  100  909k    0     0  2025k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2025k
```

But in Xcode this does not:

```
let task = Process()
let pipe = Pipe()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/curl"
task.arguments = ["--connect-timeout","10","--max-time","60","en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles","-o","/Users/username/Desktop/wikiData"]
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
```

I get this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Warning: Failed to create the file /Users/username/Desktop/wikiData: 
Warning: Operation not permitted
curl: (23) Failed writing received data to disk/application
```

How do I give curl permission to write to disk?  In Sandbox I checked "Network Incoming/Outgoing" to be able to talk to wikipedia, and set "File Access/User Selected File/Read/Write" but that doesn't seem to apply to curl. If I leave off "-o ..." I get no error. But I also seem to get no data.  Ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `curl` in an app? Why not use `URLSession` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The reason `cURL` can't write the output is it would have to have permissions which the sandbox won't allow. You should probably take the `stdout` via pipe of `cURL` and then try and write the data atomically.

```
let filePath = "/Users/username/Desktop/wikiData/the_beatles.txt"
let task = Process()

task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/curl"
task.arguments = ["--connect-timeout","10","--max-time","60","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles"]

// stdout everything to pipe
let pipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe

task.launch()

// collect output
let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

let str = output!
let filename = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

do {
    try str.write(to: filename, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
} catch {
    print("failed.")
}
```

There's likely cleaner ways to accomplish this (eg. `URLSession`), although this at least should give you some idea of how to write the data within the limitations of a sandboxed app.

Comment: Thanks I'L'I, that worked except for one small problem:```Failed writing to URL: file:///Users/username/Desktop/wikiData/the_beatles.txt, Error: You don’t have permission to save the file “the_beatles.txt” in the folder “wikiData”.``` I even set wikiData to R+W for everyone.  ???  I'll look at URLSession next.

Comment: @vonlost: Does a folder exist named "wikiData" on your Desktop? If it doesn't that might be the reason. You could try "/Users/username/Desktop/the_beatles.txt" and see if the result is any different.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change

```
let filePath = "/Users/username/Desktop/wikiData/the_beatles.txt"
```

to

```
let filePath = NSHomeDirectory() + "/wikiData"
```

Thank you for your help; it's all working now.  :-)